# Producing a particular layout on a PDF page with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, layout, itext, itextpdf

I need some help doing the layout for a PDF page using iTextSharp. If you are willing to help me, this is what I am looking for:

[image: The desired layout]

Information in red is info I will have to fetch from a db and put in.

Unfortunately I do not know the ins and outs of iTextSharp, mainly just the basics and I don't have the time at the moment to browse through the eBook they provide. I am busy finishing off other sections of this project and this would be a nice add on if anyone could help.

Comment: For tasks where I needed to convert something to look like a document, I had better luck with a .NET PDF converter/printer. I'd make a normal webpage (that just happened to look like a paperwork form) and then just print that to PDF. This way I did not get into the bowels of how to lay things out with a particular 3rd party tool, I just used HTML which I already knew.

Comment: This essentially looks like 3 tables. Simply look at table creation examples with iText, the pivotal class is `PdfPTable`.

Comment: @mkl Thank you for editing and the response I will look at it later today!

Comment: @rlb.usa thanx but i have to use itextsharp

Comment: If you want to know the ins and outs of iText(Sharp), I suggest that you take a look at iText's Developer site: http://developers.itextpdf.com/